# How to Lazy Load a collection using async-await?

Tags: c#, async-await, lazy-loading

How do I `Lazy` load the Bars collection using `async-await`? It must take an Id from the MyClass instance to get the specific collection back.

```
  public class MyClass {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Lazy<List<Bar>> Bars { get; private set; }

    public MyClass() {
      Bars = new Lazy<List<Bar>>(async () => await LoadBars(), true);
    }

    private async Task<List<Bar>> LoadBars() {
      return await Util.Database.GetBarsAsync(Id);
    } 
  }
```

This collection consumes a lot of memory so I only want it loaded when I need it.

The error I get is on the `=>`:

> Cannot convert async lambda expression to delegate type
>   'Func>'. An async lambda expression may return void, Task or
>   Task, none of which are convertible to 'Func>'

Comment: Simply you can't ... you may use `Lazy<Task<List<Bar>>> Bars  {get;private set;} => new Lazy<Task<List<Bar>>>( () => LoadBars(), true)` and `await Bars.Value`

Answer (score 1):

Short answer; you can't (without various tricks), but you can instead do this:

```
public class MyClass {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Lazy<Task<List<Bar>>> Bars { get; private set; }

    public MyClass() {
      Bars = new Lazy<Task<List<Bar>>>(() => LoadBars(), true);
    }

    private Task<List<Bar>> LoadBars() {
      return Util.Database.GetBarsAsync(Id);
    } 

    private async SomethingElseAsync() {
        List<Bar> bars = await Bars.Value;
    }
}
```